# Assigning index to two concatenated tables in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have two table with exactly the same column headers and one row each. I have the code to concatenate them which works fine.

```
data concatenation;
    set CURR_CURR CURR_30;
run;
```

However, there is no index in the output to say which row corresponds to which table.

[image]

I've tried using 'create index' and 'index create' already but they don't work syntactically. Simply I'd just want to add a column of strings and move it to the front of all the other columns in the data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INDSNAME option on the SET statement + variable to store the information.
If you set the length statement ahead of your SET statement it will create it as the first column.

Just a note that this isn't the same as an 'index'. An index in SAS has a different meaning which isn't what you're trying to create here.

```
   data concatenation;
    length dset source $50.;
    set CURR_CURR CURR_30 indsname=source;
    dset=source;
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reeza's answer is very similar to something I figured out that worked as well. Here's my version as an alternative.

```
data concatenation;
length id $ 10;

set CURR_CURR (in=a) CURR_30 (in=b);

if a then id = 'curr_curr';
else if b then id = 'curr_30';  
run;
```

Comment: This was the method to use before the INDSNAME option became available :)